# Помогите с настройкой футера

Tags: вёрстка, bootstrap

Использовал bootstrap class="navbar-fixed-bottom"(что бы прижать footer) и при прокрутке текст опускается ниже футера. Как его лучше всего настроить ? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Всего есть [шесть извесных мне способов](http://dimox.name/press_footer_bottom_with_css/), прижатия футера к низу страници возмите тот который вам подходит больше всего в зависимости от структуры и самого футера.

Comment: Спасибо вышло )